# How to add CString to const char*?

Tags: visual-c++

How to append a CString to a const char*?

```
CString custompath = "c:\folder\";
const char *one = "IECapt.exe --url=";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

There, you can find some suggestions on how to obtain what you want. E.g. you can use this snippet:

```
int     sizeOfString = custompath.GetLength();   // as in the example
size_t  destsize = sizeOfString + strlen(one) + 1;
LPTSTR  lpsz = new TCHAR[ destsize ];
_tcscpy_s(lpsz, destsize, theString);
_tcscpy_s(lpsz + sizeOfString, strlen(one)+1, one);
CString completePath(lpsz);
```

Then you can delete lpsz, if you don't need it anymore. Or, rather, you could do something like the following, from the idea (just the idea) in the section *Modifying CString Contents Directly*:

```
 LPTSTR pBuf = custompath.GetBufferSetLength(custompath.GetLength() + strlen(one) + 1);
 _tcscpy_s(pBuf + custompath.GetLength(), strlen(one) + 1, one);
 custompath.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Comment: @harper I'm going to extract the information and summarize it for the link-scared self-contained-information advocates in the next spare time slot.

Comment: This would be good and conformant with this statement "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks for contributing at Stack Overflow.